# Upload and execute a program online service

Tags: remote-access

Is there a web service where you could upload your file and execute it on the remote system?

It would probably be setup as a virtual machine with its lifespan of a single session. It would be reverted back after you'd logout/disconnect. It would probably have to share it's desktop to display application's UI.

It would probably make certain things simpler (like virus testing, UI testing etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many VPS hosting providers that people use for things like this.  No reason to use the web for it, you just pay a small fee for a remote host slice that you can do whatever with, like Slicehost.

Alternatively, many people use locally-hosted VMs.

Comment: VMs are probably the cheapest and best way to go, since you can always revert state if you infect thyself.